# RESTful API design - naming an "activity" resource

Tags: node.js, rest, api, http, express

When designing the endpoints for an `activity` resource that provides information on the activity of other resources such as `users` and `organisations` we are struggling with naming conventions.

What would be more semantic:

```
/organisations/activity
/organisations/activity/${activityId}
/users/activity
/users/activity/${activityId}
```

**OR**

```
/activity/users/${activityId}
/activity/users
/activity/organisations/${activityId}
/activity/organisations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a generic answer for this, especially since the mechanisms doing the lookup/retrieval at the other end, and associated back-ends vary so drastically, not to mention the use case purpose and intended application.

That said, assuming for all intents and purposes the "schema" (or ... endpoint convention from the point of view of the end user) was just going to be flat, I have seen many more of the latter **activity** convention, as that is the actual resource, which is what many applications and APIs are developed around.

I've come to expect the following style of representation from APIs today (how they achieve the referencings and mappings is a different story, but from the point of view of API reference)
 -

```
{
    "Activity": [
        {
        "date": "1970-01-01 08:00:00",
        "some_other_resource_reference_uuid": "f1c4a41e-1639-4e35-ba98-e7b169d1c92d",
        "user": "b3ababc4-461b-404a-a1a2-83b4ca8c097f",
        "uuid": "0ccf1b41-aecf-45f9-a963-178128096c97"
        }
    ],
    "Users": [
        {
        "email": "johnanderson@mycompany.net",
        "first": "John",
        "last": "Anderson",
        "user_preference_1": "somevalue",
        "user_property_1": "somevalue",
        "uuid": "b3ababc4-461b-404a-a1a2-83b4ca8c097f"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

The  [**StackExchange** API](https://api.stackexchange.com) allows retrieving objects through multiple methods also:

For example, the **[User](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)** type look like this:
 -

```
{
    "view_count": 1000,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "user_id": 9999,
    "link": "http://example.stackexchange.com/users/1/example-user",
    "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?d=identicon&r=PG",
    "display_name": "Example User"
}
```

And on the **[Question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)** type, the same user is shown underneath the **owner** object :
 -

```
{
    "owner": {
        "user_id": 9999,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a007be5a61f6aa8f3e85ae2fc18dd66e?d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name": "Example User",
        "link": "https://example.stackexchange.com/users/1/example-user"
    },
    "is_answered": false,
    "view_count": 31415,
    "favorite_count": 1,
    "down_vote_count": 2,
    "up_vote_count": 3,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "score": 1,
    "last_activity_date": 1494871135,
    "creation_date": 1494827935,
    "last_edit_date": 1494896335,
    "question_id": 1234,
    "link": "https://example.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/an-example-post-title",
    "title": "An example post title",
    "body": "An example post body"
}
```

---

On the [Posts Type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post) reference (Using this as a separate example because there is only a handful of methods to reach this type), you'll see an example down the bottom :

**Methods That Return This Type**

[posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts) 
  [posts/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids) 
 
  [users/{ids}/posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-users) 2.2 
  [me/posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-posts) 2.2

So whilst you can access resources (or "types" as it is on StackExchange), through a number of ways including [filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) and [complex queries](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max), there still exists the ability to see the desired resource through a number of more direct transparent URI conventions.

---

**Different applications** will clearly have different requirements.  For example, the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) is **user based** all the way - this makes sense from a users point of view given that in the context of the authenticated credential, you're separating one users objects from another.

This doesn't mean **google** uses the same convention for all of their APIs, their [Activities API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities) resource is all about the **activity**

Even looking at the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference), there is a [Direct Messages](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/direct_messages) endpoint resource that has **sender** and **receiver** objects within.

I've not seen many API's at all that are limited to accessing resources purely via a **user** endpoint, unless the situation *obviously* calls for it, i.e. the Gmail example above.

Regardless of how flexible a REST API can be, the minimum I have come to expect is that some kind of **Activity**, location, physical object, or other entity is usually it's own resource, and the user association is plugged in and referenced at various degrees of flexibility (at a minimum, the example given at the top of this post).

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan nod.  Sorry for the lack of supporting info.  I've been trying to edit this every chance I get ... But if I had a dollar for every time "*Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted*" came up - sheesh

Answer (score 1):

It should be pointed out that in a true REST api the uri holds no meaning. It's the link relationships from your organizations and users resources that matter.

Clients should just discover those urls, and should also adapt to the new situation if you decide that you want a different url structure after all.

That being said, it's nice to have a logical structure for this type of thing. However, either is fine. You're asking for an opinion, there is not really a standard or best practice. That said, I would choose option #1.